# Save/read data to/from textfile

Tags: python, numpy, save, text-files

I have the following two series:

```
self.MW_x = ..
self.MW_x = .. (from previous calculations)
```

and I zip them together like this:

```
self.MW_final = list(zip(self.MW_x, self.MW_y))
```

and try to save them with `numpy.savetxt`

```
np.savetxt("testfile.txt", self.MW_final, delimiter = ";", header = "x_Value, y_Value")
```

If I plot it directly (self.MW_x, self.MW_y) it looks like this, which is perfect:

[image: perfect plot]

but if I try to plot the saved textfile again, it looks like this:

[image: entirely wrong]

I just don't know what happened on the way to the file and back.

Comment: how to you plot from the textfile?  codes will be good.

Comment: Please show us how you load the text file and plot it.

Comment: Please don't put picture links in your question. Add the pictures themselfs to the question. And be more specific in the title of your question please. And specifiy the python version you are asking about.

Comment: @buhtz Remember that embedding pictures is limited by reputation - not all users can do it.

Comment: I embedded the plots and cleaned up some spelling and grammar.  You still need to show us how you load the file and plot it, though.

Comment: I actually figured it out now. It was my mistake when importing the file.

Comment: @Ajean I didn't remember but know I know. :D It is a bad solution because it produces questions of low quality and with security risk (because of URLs).

Answer (score 0):

Are you tied to exporting it via numpy with the semicolon delimiter? If not, it would be a lot easier to simply export via Pandas as well. i.e.)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"x_value":self.MW_x, "y_value": self.MW_y})
df.to_csv("testfile.txt")

df_again = pd.read_csv("testfile.txt")
```

Also, in the answer you posted to this question you have:

```
x_val = df.ix[0:]
y_val = df.ix[1:]
```

which is returning *rows* 0 through N (N = len(df)) for x_val and *rows* 1 through N for y_val. This is why you're getting two arrays with two different lengths.

To call a column from a pandas DataFrame you can write:

```
x_val = df['col_name1']
y_val = df['col_name2']
```

Or, more simply, if 'col_name2' is your x-axis variable then you can do:

```
df.set_index('col_name2', inplace = True)
df.plot()
```

which will plot the variable 'col_name1' on the y-axis against 'col_name2' on the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the first 5 rows of the data at every step (first 5 rows of self.MW_x, self.MW_final, /Users/sping/Desktop/testfile.txt, df, x_val, and y_val) to figure out where the data is changing?

I think you have a problem with how you're using ix

```
x_val = df.ix[0:]
y_val = df.ix[1:]
```

Doesn't grab the first and second column. It grabs the first row until the end  `[0:]` and the second row until the end `[1:]`. As a result, x_val will be 1 row longer than y_val. You want to use

```
x_val = df.ix[:,0]
y_val = df.ix[:,1]
```

The first argument to ix gives you the rows and the second argument gives you the columns.

Also you want to set header=0 or just leave it as default if you want to use the column headers. Python uses zero indexing so the first row is row 0, not row 1.

I looks like you have some typos in the code you've posted. You're also using ';' as a delimiter when saving with np.savetxt and ',' as a delimiter when reading using pd.read_csv.

Comment: they are not actual typos. the second part of the code is just the plot with python, but I compared it to an excel plot, which gives me the same result. for this I created a csv file instead of the txt, hence the ';' separator.